# Style Disabled Button and icon inside that button

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have 2 buttons, normal and disabled.

This is my code:

```css
.btn.disabled {
  color: #ccc;
  background: none;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
}


/* Try #1 */
.btn.disabled>.fa {
  color: #ccc;
}
/* Try #2 */
.btn.disabled .fa {
  color: #ccc;
}
/* Try #3 */
.btn.disabled i {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm disabled"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger "></i></a>
```

I keep getting

[image]

How do I make my `fa icon` silver?

and

What is wrong with what I got?

Comment: In [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/6pgdqz4h/1/) it's silver with your first try. You probably have another style with higher precedence setting the color. Can't reproduce with the code you provided. If you use Chrome dev tools and inspect the element, then look at the Computed styles you can see what style is setting the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A higher priority rule must be setting the red colour. As per [T.Short's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59429350/1921385) you'll have to override it. In this example i'm using `color:inherit` to take on the parent's colour:

```css
.btn.disabled {
    color: #ccc;
    background: none;
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
}
/* this (or something similar) is making it red */
.btn i.text-danger {
    color: red;
}
/* overide it to inherit the parent's color */
.btn.disabled i.text-danger {
    color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm disabled" ><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger ">[icon]</i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `.text-danger` is making the icon red and is getting priority.

try something like:

```
.btn.disabled .text-danger {
    color: #ccc;
}
```